# FCM Refresh Token always output NotRegistered

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my current project, I uninstall the app from my phone then I begin to get `NotRegistered` whenever I try to send **push notification** to this Phone **Token**

so, I deleted the token from my server, then I called `FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();` when the user logout, knowing that **Token** is associated with the device, not the user's account.

So now when the User login I call this `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();` to get the new token, and update the user account like this

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) async {
      print('TOKEN _$value');
      print('FireaseTOKEN :$value');

      String userId = await LocalStorageService.getString(LocalStorageService.userId) ?? "";

      final myUser = await ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).getUser(userId);

      if (myUser != null && myUser.firebaseToken != value) {
        myUser.firebaseToken = value;

        await ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).updateUser(myUser);
      }
    });
```

the new token is generated but the issue now is when I send a message to this new **Token** I always get `NotRegistered`

Please, am I doing it the right way or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code) --- If you need to show how the code executes, use `print` statements for that. If you share them in code and share the output, we can correlate from that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i will take note of that hence fort, thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, about this issue, please whats your view on it?

Comment: Rather than taking note in future posts, edit this one (there's a link right under it) to address the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to resolve this issue,
my above Code is good and clean, what I needed to do for the token to be refreshed was to logout from the device, uninstall the app from my phone then install it again,

This i have tested this on Android and iPhone (12 pro max) and it works beautifully